# Why the code to Remove string and update the dataset is not working?

Tags: python, string, list, function, for-loop

Firstly, thanks for your time and help. I am trying to remove some unwanted characters from a string and include in the dataset which in this case is a list, but when I print the dataset later nothing changed and it doesn't return any error.
This dataset is a list of the lists, so there are other lists inside this dataset representing rows. In the end, I am just working with one of the list columns which is the index_cleaning (the one I want to remove the bad characters). These bad characters are represented in a list.

The data comes from the source below:
https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps

The input with the field to be modified highlighted can be seen below:

[image]

The output would be a dataset in the same format (list) without the + and commas as float.

```
def cleaning_data(dataset,index_cleaning,list_bad_words,header=False):
        if header:
            start_row=1
        else:
            start_row=0
        for app in dataset:
            if app[index_cleaning] in list_bad_words:
                word=app[index_cleaning]
                dataset[start_row][index_cleaning]=dataset[start_row][index_cleaning].remove(app[index_cleaning])
                for char in list_bad_words:
                    word=word.replace(char,'')
                dataset[start_row][index_cleaning]=dataset[start_row][index_cleaning].insert(index_cleaning,word)
            start_row+=1
        return dataset
bad_word=[',','+']
google_data=cleaning_data(google_free,5,bad_word)
google_data
```

Comment: Please, can you update your question and put there sample input and expected output?

Comment: Your code has obvious indentation errors. What the correct inlentation should be is less obvious. Please [edit] to mix this, and also include some sample data so we can test the code, and the expected output for that data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just changed my post. There is no indentation error. It was just a copy and paste issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the data and remove `,` and `+` from desired column, you can use this example:

```
import csv

dataset = []
with open('googleplaystore.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    next(reader)    # skip headers
    for row in reader:
        # clean the desired column:
        row[5] = row[5].replace(',', '').replace('+', '')
        dataset.append(row)

for app in dataset:
    print(app)
```

Prints:

```
...

['FR Calculator', 'FAMILY', '4.0', '7', '2.6M', '500', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Education', 'June 18, 2017', '1.0.0', '4.1 and up']
['FR Forms', 'BUSINESS', 'NaN', '0', '9.6M', '10', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Business', 'September 29, 2016', '1.1.5', '4.0 and up']
['Sya9a Maroc - FR', 'FAMILY', '4.5', '38', '53M', '5000', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Education', 'July 25, 2017', '1.48', '4.1 and up']
['Fr. Mike Schmitz Audio Teachings', 'FAMILY', '5.0', '4', '3.6M', '100', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Education', 'July 6, 2018', '1.0', '4.1 and up']
['Parkinson Exercices FR', 'MEDICAL', 'NaN', '3', '9.5M', '1000', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Medical', 'January 20, 2017', '1.0', '2.2 and up']
['The SCP Foundation DB fr nn5n', 'BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE', '4.5', '114', 'Varies with device', '1000', 'Free', '0', 'Mature 17+', 'Books & Reference', 'January 19, 2015', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device']
['iHoroscope - 2018 Daily Horoscope & Astrology', 'LIFESTYLE', '4.5', '398307', '19M', '10000000', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Lifestyle', 'July 25, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Andrej. Based in what you posted I was able to change my code here:

```
def cleaning_data(dataset,index_cleaning,list_bad_words,header=False):
    data=[]
    if header:
        next(dataset) #Skip headers
    for row in dataset:
        for char in list_bad_words:
            row[index_cleaning]=row[index_cleaning].replace(char,'')
            data.append(row)
    return data
bad_word=[',','+']
google_data_cleaned=cleaning_data(google_free,5,bad_word)
google_data_cleaned
```